# Get genre name corresponding to genre_id in TMDB API

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit

Could you please help me? I try to get the movie title, image, and genre from TMDB API and show it in recycler view. I managed to get the image and title but I have problems with the genre. Instead of the genre names I get an array of integers. How can I get names instead? Should I create a hashmap with ids and names and somehow get the names from there? How would you do that?

[image]

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "From DC Comics comes the Suicide Squad, an antihero team of incarcerated supervillains who act as deniable assets for the United States government, undertaking high-risk black ops missions in exchange for commuted prison sentences.",
      "release_date": "2016-08-03",
      "genre_ids": [
        14,
        28,
        80
      ],
      "id": 297761,
      "original_title": "Suicide Squad",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Suicide Squad",
      "backdrop_path": "/ndlQ2Cuc3cjTL7lTynw6I4boP4S.jpg",
      "popularity": 48.261451,
      "vote_count": 1466,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.91
    },
```

This is MovieResponce class:

```
public class MovieResponse {
    @SerializedName("results")
    ArrayList<Movie> results;

    public ArrayList<Movie> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(ArrayList<Movie> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

This is my Movie model:

```
public class Movie {
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String posterPath;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    ArrayList<Integer> genre;

    public ArrayList<Integer> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

Recyclerview:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie recyclerViewItem = movieList.get(position);

        holder.movieTitleTv.setText(recyclerViewItem.getTitle());
        holder.genreTv.setText(recyclerViewItem.getGenre().toString());

        String poster = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + recyclerViewItem.getPosterPath();
        Glide.with(context).load(poster).apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()).into(holder.image);

    }
```

Callback:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_star_movie);


        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.activityMain_recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new MoviesRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movieList);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MovieResponse> call = apiService.getPopularMovies("9c4b9deab9d391df1258857ba5f58b9c");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                     movieList = response.body().getResults();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movieList));
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    Log.e("event success", " " + response.body().toString());
                } else {
                    Log.e("Message", "sorry!.......we are unable to fetch user info .......");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Response = " + t.toString());
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [genres list](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list) endpoint to get a list of all the ids and names. Save those to a HashMap to quickly look up when you get your movies.